# Kali Linux on VirtulBox showing a black screen after full boot

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager to launch KaliLinux. When I open the virtual machine on my laptop (16gb ram) the only thing that shows up is a black screen after the boot. I tried "to scroll to the line that starts with "linux" and remove "quiet" and add "noreplace-paravirt"". This didn't work though. Does anyone know anything I could do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I found that it's best to max out the memory given to the video adaptor within VirtualBox.

Comment: Can you start Kali to a terminal screen with Ctrl-Alt-F1? if so try   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove   ...  and then restart and test.

Comment: When I do Ctrl-Alt-F1 on boot nothing happens. Is there another way to access the terminal screen?

Comment: I have used Ctrl-Alt-F1 when starting, not after startup has occurred and failed.  Restart again and try Ctrl-Alt-F1 at the beginning of the startup (even twice) to see if that works.

Comment: I tried Cltrl+Alt+F1 but nothing happens, but I am able to get to the login screen on my virtual machine and login, but after that there is a black screen.

Comment: You may need to re-install Kali at this point. I have Kali working well here.